# The use of the definite article to refer to generic nouns

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, generic

I was reading [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)'s [dissertation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/) on the use of generic nouns and found the following example sentences.

***correct*** : (A) The unicorn is a mythical beast resembling the horse.

***correct*** : (B) The unicorn is a mythical beast resembling a horse.

***wrong*** :   (C) The unicorn is a mythical beast resembling the horse ***with a single horn***.

***correct*** : (D) The unicorn is a mythical beast resembling a horse ***with a single horn***.

The first two sentences (A) and (B) are both syntactically correct and have the same meaning.

However, when the phrase ***"with a single horn"*** is added to the first two sentences (A) and (B), which leads to sentences (C) and (D), respectively,
(C) is wrong but (D) is correct.

My question is : what is wrong with sentence (C) ?

Comment: I think _''the horse with a single horn''_ is wrong, because there is no horse with a single horn. (D) is correct, because  _the unicorn_ resembles a horse, but isn't. It shares many characteristics of horses, with one exception:  that it has _ a single horn_. In other words, the unicorn is almost like a horse, except for the fact that it has _a single horn_ (which actual horses do not have).

Comment: Not clear what kind of answer you are looking for. The addition of "with a single horn" makes the reference to the horse specific and therefore prevents a generic interpretation: there is no class of horses with a single horn.

Comment: (D) may be paraphrased "The unicorn doesn't exist and never has done. It 'is' a mythical beast. There is a quite well-defined image of 'what one looks like': think of a horse. Now think of a 45cm (say) straight horn projecting from the forehead." // (C) would have to be rendered (from the colon) "... : You know those horses with 45cm (say) straight horns projecting from their foreheads? ..."